# passing a bash variable to pytest

Tags: python, bash, pytest

I am having a problem passing a bash variable to pytests. Here is what gets run:

```
FILES="$(git ls-files)"
python3.6 -m pytest -q tests/TestStructure.py --myoption=$FILES[0] --junitxml results.xml
```

This is what is in $FILES if i print it to the terminal:

```
README.md controls_remediation/__init__.py controls_remediation/control_handler.py controls_remediation/dbfunctions.py controls_remediation/main.py controls_remediation/pandafunctions.py controls_remediation/utilities/CONSTANTS.py controls_remediation/utilities/__init__.py controls_remediation/utilities/hadoopconnect.py controls_remediation/utilities/log_helper.py controls_remediation/utilities/settings_constants.py kafka_controls/KAFKACONSTANTS.py kafka_controls/__init__.py kafka_controls/producer.py setup.py tests/TestStructure.py tests/__init__.py tests/conftest.py tests/functional/TestFunctional.py tests/functional/__init__.py tests/unit/TestKafka.py tests/unit/TestPandaFunctions.py tests/unit/__init__.py
```

Here is what TestStructure.py looks like:

```
import pytest


def test_answer(myoption):
    if myoption == "this":
        print ("do this option")
    elif myoption == "that":
        print ("do that option")
    else:
        print(myoption)
    assert 0
```

And here is what conftest.py looks like:

```
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--myoption", action="store", default="that",
        help="my option: this or that")


@pytest.fixture
def myoption(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--myoption")
```

This is the error I am getting when I run pytest using the first piece:

```
no tests ran in 0.00 seconds
ERROR: file not found: tests/unit/__init__.py[0]
```

I really have no clue how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the first element of the array just by naming the array: `$FILES`.

You can also access the first element by putting the index, but you have to enclose the expression in curly braces: `${FILES[0]}`.

By using `$FILES[0]`, you are expanding `$FILES` and then adding `[0]` to that string.

Try:

```
FILES="$(git ls-files)"
python3.6 -m pytest -q tests/TestStructure.py --myoption=${FILES[0]} --junitxml results.xml
```